# MVC 5 Change Layout by settings of user

Tags: templates, asp.net-mvc-5

I need advise on how to implement what I am trying to do. Basically what I need is a way to switch the theme of the website based on the settings for the logged in user.

For example, let's say there's a Sales group. And the sales group users have their own individual login. The Admin of the website will use a list of available layouts displayed (as an image) to select how the header, footer and the content of the page should look like for the sales group users. So when the sales user logs in, they see their website with the selected header, footer and content layout.

This is to handle situations where some groups need more information while some groups require fancy design rather than information. The content will be more or less the same so I was thinking of using the same controllers for all the users' views. But the way it's represented will look different. One group will have big images and big texts highlighting the important data while another will have more information than images. How it is displayed will be selected by the Admin in the back end.

Anyone have any suggestion on how to implement this? Is there a theme technique or some other way this can be done?

I would appreciate any ideas to implement a website in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are 2 ways you can achieve this... Or in the controller, or in the view itself...

In the controller (you can decide for which user you want to return which layout:

```
return View("Details", "_Layout", model);
```

In the view (Decide there what user can have which layout):

```
@{
   if (User == "Admin")
   {
      Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
   }
   else
   {
      Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Inside view method (View model, extra info):

```
public class LayoutViewModel
{
    public LayoutViewModel() {}

    public LayoutViewModel(string layout) {
        Layout = layout;
    }

    public string Layout { get; set; }
}

public class CustomViewModel : LayoutViewModel
{
}
```

Comment: I thought about handling it in the controller. Can't do it in View since the layout choice has to be retrieved from the database.

Question: Is it possible to have a global model that can be accessed from any view? If so, I can create a Model for the template and set the choice of layout in there and then let the View use them when rendering.

Comment: If you want to use the view method, I would create a base class where I put the property that will come back on any view... If you want to do it in the controller method, just replace my string"_Layout" by the database value.